# Array withother classes - object - Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have 3 classes: `Course`, `CourseEntry` and `Transcript`. In transcript, I have a function to add courses, like that:

```
public class Transcript {
    CourseEntry coursestaken[] = new CourseEntry[6];

    public void addCourse(Course course)
    {
        coursestaken[lastIndexOf(getCoursestaken())] = new CourseEntry(course);
    }
    (lastIndexOf gives me the empty array index - it's working on)
```

And in my `CourseEntry`:

```
public class CourseEntry {
    Course course;
    char grade = 'I';

    public CourseEntry(Course course)
    {
        this.course = course;
    }
```

And in my `Course`:

```
public  class Course {
    int courseNumber,credits;
    String courseName;

    public Course addNewCourse(int courseNumber, int credits, String courseName)
    {
        this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
        this.credits = credits;
        this.courseName = courseName;

        return this;
    }
```

In my main:

```
Transcript t = new Transcript();
Course course = new Course();

Course matematik = course.addNewCourse(1, 2, "Matematik");
t.addCourse(matematik);

Course turkce = course.addNewCourse(1, 4, "Türkçe");
t.addCourse(turkce);
```

But if I loop coursestaken array, it prints the last inserted index for all.

How can I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: `Course.addNewCourse` *mutates/changes/updates* the current object (and doesn't "add" it to anything). Instead, remove that method and used `new Course` (the constructor should be updated to take courseNumber, credits, courseName) and then add the *new* Course object to the Transcript.

Comment: please include the loop code as well as the stack trace

Comment: wow reading that code really hurt my brain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are **references** in Java, that is, pointers to the objects. So when you do:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = a;
```

You're NOT copying the whole object `a` to `b`, but copying **the reference to `a`** to `b` (the memory address). So both `a` and `b` are references to the object created by `new`.

Let's follow your code so you see what's happening:

```
Course course = new Course();
Course matematik = course.addNewCourse(1, 2, "Matematik");
    this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
    this.credits = credits;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    return this;
```

Here you modified `course` object. `matematik` now is also the same as `course` because it points to same object.

```
Course turkce = course.addNewCourse(1, 4, "Türkçe");
```

Here you modify `course` again. Now `course`, `turkce` and `matematik` are all referencing the same object, which you created first with `Course course = new Course();`.

I think most easy way to fix this is that you create a constructor with parameters:

```
public class Course {
...
     public Course(int courseNumber,int credits,String courseName) {
           this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
           this.credits = credits;
           this.courseName = courseName;
     }
}
```

and then

```
  Course matematik = new Course(1, 2, "Matematik");
  t.addCourse(matematik);

  Course turkce = new Course(1, 4, "Türkçe");
  t.addCourse(turkce);
```

Comment: Thanks for all , really thanks. But , i wonder that, with use that new  so that create a new object, will make space more on ram or wherever ? This is the best way ( for performance ) or easiest way ?

Comment: You're welcome. This is a common mistake when learning Java. Yes, it takes more RAM and you should avoid doing `new` if you can. In your case, however, you cannot avoid creating a new object because you want to store different data each time and keep it, so the more data you add, the more RAM you will use, obviously :) And don't worry, computers this days can take a lot more than that ;)

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a new `Course` object for each course, your `addNewCourse` method only mutates the current `Course` object. Modify `Course` like so:

```
public class Course {
    private final int courseNumber;
    private final int credits;
    private final String courseName;

    public Course(int courseNumber, int credits, String courseName) {
        this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
        this.credits = credits;
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public int getCourseNumber() {
        return courseNumber;
    }

    public int getCredits() {
        return credits;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
}
```

And then use the following:

```
Transcript t = new Transcript();

Course matematik = new Course(1, 2, "Matematik");
t.addCourse(matematik);

Course turkce = new Course(1, 4, "Türkçe");
t.addCourse(turkce);
```

Comment: Thanks for all , really thanks. But , i wonder that, with use that new  so that create a new object, will make space more on ram or wherever ? This is the best way ( for performance ) or easiest way ?

Comment: @MuhammetArslan There is no other way to do what you are describing except to allocate an object per course.